# ASP Javascript Add Option to Select Element in Javascript Can't Work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a ASP Drop Down List in the Main Page. When I clicked a button, a pop up window with a list data appear. When I clicked a row, I will extract the necessary value from the table row and set it to the Drop Down in the Main Page.

```
//This chunk of code is the action when user click the table row in the Pop Up.

//Access the Drop Down element from Main Page from this Pop Up Page
var InternalOrderDDL = window.opener.document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_InternalOrderDDL" + rowID);

//Clear all item in this Drop Down
InternalOrderDDL.options.length = 0;

//Add elements to this Drop Down
AddOption("--", "", InternalOrderDDL);
AddOption(text, value, InternalOrderDDL);

function AddOption(text, value, element) {
     var option = document.createElement("option");
     element.options.add(option); // Google Chrome works very well but IE has an error "Unspecified error" when hit this line.

     option.value = value;
     option.innerHTML = text;
}
```

Basically, everything works really well in Google Chrome but Internet Explorer are having this issues.

Is it due to the Pop Up Window?

Answer (score 0):

```
function AddOption(text, value, element) {
     var option = document.createElement("option");
     option.value = value;
     option.innerHTML = text;
     element.options.add(option);     
}
```

Comment: Kindly add some explanation

Comment: empty options are written in the dom as self-closing. eg. <option/>. MS browsers are unable to create an innerHTML value for it, since it is written as self-closing. So for interoperability, follow a design pattern. create element, set some of its properties and attributes, then append it to a container element/partent. NOT create element. append it to a container, set some of its properties and attributes.

Comment: Thank you, that is a very nice explanation, what I originally meant is to update the answer to contain this info so it will become more complete and clearer.